# How to use new Vue in a single file component?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, vue.js

I'm still learning Vue.js and I have a minor issue:
I have a single file component with an array of checkboxes, and I have looked at the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox) for using multiple checkboxes, but the example there requires me to declare:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#example-3',
  data: {
    checkedNames: []
  }
})
```

**Edit** However I have set this up in my single file component within the `<script>` tag within data(), but it just checks/unchecks all boxes at once (but feeds back true/false correctly):

```js
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'PhrasesDetail',
    data () {
      return {
        game: '',
        language: '',
        checkedPhrasesArr: {
             el: '#selection',
             data: {
                 checkedPhrasesArr: []
             }
          }
      }
    },
... 
</script>
```

**The Question is** where and how do I declare the checkbox array so that it reacts/recognises the **individual** elements?

These are my checkboxes:

```
 <tr v-for="(keyTransPair, index) in this.language.data">
      <td id="selection"><input type="checkbox" :id="index" v-model="checkedPhrasesArr"></td>
      <td>{{index}}</td>
 ...
 </tr>
```

Comment: You're supposed to start Vue ( `new Vue({ ... })` ) in a js file. Single file components are for, well, components.

Comment: You just don´t need the `new Vue(...)` code block. You already added the `checkedPhrasesArr` variable correctly into the `data()` function.

Comment: @Schlangguru when I have just that though it checks all boxes at once and still outputs null in when I `{{checkedPhrasesArr}}`

Comment: @Schlangguru edited the question a little - if I have it just as `checkedPhrasesArr: []` - I get null whenever I check a box (which checks all boxes), with what I have in the question - I get true/false, but it still checks/unchecks all boxes at once

Comment: I think you get the data of vue components wrong. `checkedPhrasesArr` is your view-model. You want to have an array there so it should be `checkedPhrasesArr: []`. Also you need to define the value in your input checkboxes.

Comment: @Schlangguru ah that may be why I get null with `checkedPhrasesArr: []` - I will try adding values and get back to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have assembled a complete example. (I don´t  know anything about your `language.data` object so I´m just using fake data).

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- Your Checkboxes -->
    <table>
      <tr v-for="(keyTransPair, index) in language.data">
        <td id="selection"><input type="checkbox" :value="keyTransPair" :id="index" v-model="checkedPhrasesArr"></td>
        <td>{{index}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <!-- Show the selected boxes -->
    {{ checkedPhrasesArr }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data () {
    return {
      // Your language data
      language: {
        data: {
          keyOne: "one",
          keyTwo: "two",
          keyThree: "three"
        }
      },

      // The Checkbox data
      checkedPhrasesArr: []
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Note** that the checkbox values are bound with `:value="keyTransPair"`. You can change the value to anything you want. This value will be added to the array if the checkbox is checked.

---

By the way: You use `<td id="selection">` within the `v-for` loop. So the id "selection" will not be unique. You should better use a class instead of an id here.